# What is the process of this site getting its own design?

Tags: support, design

When does this site get its own design and how will be choose the designer? I would like to make a webdesign design proposal then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Stack Exchange works is that when a beta site is close to coming out of beta, Stack Exchange staff will develop the final look and feel of the site with the help of the community and the [protem moderators](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/37) who are helping to guide it. That is why we have questions such as [What should the theme and layout look like?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/37) here on meta.

Answers to this question can make suggestions about the look and feel of the site, suggest logos, discuss options and generally thrash out a design.

You are more than welcome to post some ideas there and comment on the ideas already generated.

As it is, we are [some way away from getting out of beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics). We probably need to triple our visits per day, double our number of regular active users and most of all we need to regularly generate many more high quality *Robotics* questions. Few graduated sites (those out of beta) generate less than 5 questions a day, so that is our most important statistic to improve.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the meta question. I would like the community to grow, too. By the way, I thought the concept of a robot for two years, and now I start to implement that. So from me there will raise many questions in the next weeks. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Futher to Mark's answer, while I don't put too much effort into following the stats, the one that bugs me a bit is:

```
committed users
274 users committed
77% signed up for beta
6.9% fulfilled commitment

followers
287 users followed
49.8% signed up for beta
```

Only **6.9%** fulfilled their commitment!!

Comment: This is fairly typical. There is at least one [launched site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) with a single digit *fulfilled commitment* stat and there are many [beta sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) much older than *Robotics* with similarly poor conversion.