# New site look coming soon & Code of Conduct available for review

Tags: discussion, status-planned, stackexchange

## New Site theme coming soon

A few weeks ago it was announced on [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) that new site themes were rolling out across the Stack Exchange Network.

Initially 10 Stack Exchange sites will have new themes similar to the new look over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

When our theme upgrade comes, we will get the stock theme, something like this:

[image: Stock Stack Exchange Theme - Question list]
[image: Stack Stack Exchange Theme - Question]

For those who are interested, more details on the history and reasoning behind these changes can be found over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com):

- [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365/138432)
- [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/138432)
- [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/138432)

---

## Feedback requested for New Stack Exchange Code of Conduct

I would also encourage people to take a look at the [Stack Exchange Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review?cb=1) and provide feedback on the update to our current [Be Nice policy](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), if you have thoughts.

We want *Robotics* to be a welcoming place for everyone, so having clear guidelines about what is acceptable is key to ensuring that we our site is not a home for bigotry, intolerance or impatience.

Comment: With this in mind, I think [this post](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/20709) and [this post](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/20709) should be 'renewed' regarding R.SE site themes.

Comment: I've updated them both with [meta-tag:status-deferred] tags and closed the latter, as it won't be relevant until we are big enough for a custom design.