# Given the recent graduation from Beta, what’s next?

Tags: discussion, design

Robotics SE graduated out of Beta status in December 2021, see [Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta).

The niche nature of Robotics SE (discussed in a number of posts in Robotics Meta SE) is unlikely to change, but I was wondering what *might* change now and what the benefits are?

The topic that got me on to this thread was the look of the site. Is it correct that changing the icon and site theme is an option now? See [Can we get an icon?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/can-we-get-an-icon)

Other than aesthetics are there other benefits to be considered post-graduation?

Comment: Related: [Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2023](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1491/30413)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, very little will change. The main thing is that we no longer have "Beta" sitting ominously in the header. Hopefully that will result in fewer people thinking we might disappear at any moment and not engage as much as they might otherwise do.

Reputation levels and site design only only come with a much bigger site, so there's no real need to do anything other than keep encouraging people to ask and answer questions.

Having said that, we have been making plans and there is a potential way we might be able to grow our community, and we hope that we might be able to start making announcements about these plans in the not too distant future.

Comment: To clarify, site design isn't directly tied to the size/activity of the site, but rather the availability of staff designers. That said, a large/active site that's been out of beta for a while would probably be prioritized more highly than a smaller/lower-activity site that just left beta. As for increasing reputation thresholds for privileges to "full site" levels, it's sort of up to when this site's community thinks it's ready to do so – the important thing to ensure is that there are still enough users with each privilege to maintain the quality of the site.

Comment: Thanks @V2Blast, that's pretty much what I was trying to say, sorry if it came across otherwise.