# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2023

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

**Summary**: Robotics Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/election/1) on May 9th 2023, as your “graduation” election as a [result of having lost your beta label a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta).

The timeline:

- On May 2nd, we will post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on May 9th, users can [nominate themselves](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected from the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On May 16th, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods), and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on May 24th (or May 31st, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.